# Create exim filter to restrict outgoing emails to a limited few

Tags: exim

I'm trying to restrict users from sending email to any domain outside of a few selected domains, outlook.com and gmail.com in this example, I've been playing around with a filter something like below but this will allow the mail be sent to any domain as long gmail/outlook is also included ! My brain just can't make it work !

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

```
# Exim filter
#
# test1 & test2 are not restricted
# test3 & test4 are restricted to @outlook.com and @gmail.com, i.e. cannot send to any other domain

# these email addresses are not restricted
if $sender_address is "test1@example.com" or $sender_address is "test2@example.com"
then
    finish
endif

if $sender_address_domain is "example.com" and ("$h_to:, $h_cc:, $h_bcc:" does not contain "@outlook.com" and "$h_to:, $h_cc:, $h_bcc:" does not contain "@gmail.com") 
then
    fail text "Sorry one or more of your email recipients is not allowed."
    finish
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this working. For anyone interested in doing something similar, here is the what I used :

```
# Exim filter
#
# test1 & test2 are not restricted in this example

if $sender_address_domain is "example.com" 
    # these email addresses are not restricted
    if $sender_address_local_part is "test1" or $sender_address_local_part is "test2" #etc
    then
        finish
    endif

    if foranyaddress $recipients ( $thisaddress does not contain "@allowed1.com" and $thisaddress does not contain "@allowed3.com" and $thisaddress does not contain "@allowed3.com" ) #etc
    then
        fail text "Email blocked. One or more of your email recipients is not allowed."
        finish
    endif
endif
```